# A problem with Deploy and Locator in a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I recently asked a question about Locators not behaving properly (see [Locators and Table within a Manipulate are not behaving](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/locators-and-table-within-a-manipulate-are-not-behaving)) and thought I had figured out the answer. However, as I played around to figure out why the problem existed in the first place I discovered that using Deploy caused the problem to return. Here is as simple of an example as I can come up with that reproduces the problem and maintains some of the features that I need in the Manipulate. Particularly, I need to link the two sliders with the Locator. The following works fine:

```
Manipulate[
 vector = Graphics[{Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, p}], 
    Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = #; x = p[[1]]; y = p[[2]]) &]]}]; 
 Show[{vector}, PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, 
  ImageSize -> 500], 
 Row[{"Ax", Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (x = #; p[[1]] = x) &], {-2, 2}], 
   Spacer[4], Dynamic[x]}], 
 Row[{"Ay", Manipulator[Dynamic[y, (y = #; p[[2]] = y) &], {-2, 2}], 
   Spacer[4], Dynamic[y]}],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, None},
 {{x, 1}, None},
 {{y, 1}, None},
 TrackedSymbols -> {x, y, p}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You get a green arrow that you can move with either the Locator or the Sliders (one component at a time).

However, if the user clicks slightly off of the Locator they highlight the whole graphics image and go into an editing mode. Users unfamiliar with this may not know what to do so I want to prevent this by using Deploy.

Adding Deployed->True as an option to the Manipulate doesn't work. The documentation for Manipulate says that it should, but for some reason it does nothing here.

So instead I wrapped Deploy around Show:

```
 Deploy@Show[{vector}, PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, 
  ImageSize -> 500],
```

Now the user doesn't accidentally go into editing mode, but the Locator doesn't work. The Sliders do move the vector around and the Locator moves with them, but I can't move the locator with the mouse except for a VERY small distance at a time.

I'm wondering if this might have something to do with how I have linked the various control variables using the second argument of Dynamic. Perhaps the solution to this is also ultimately the solution to the question I referenced above.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{vector},
  vector = 
   Graphics[{Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[p]}], 
     Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = #; x = p[[1]]; y = p[[2]]) &]]}];
  Deploy@Show[vector,
    PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, ImageSize -> 500]],

 Row[{"Ax", Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (x = #; p[[1]] = x) &], {-2, 2}], 
   Spacer[4], Dynamic[x]}], 
 Row[{"Ay", Manipulator[Dynamic[y, (y = #; p[[2]] = y) &], {-2, 2}], 
   Spacer[4], Dynamic[y]}],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, None},
 {{x, 1}, None},
 {{y, 1}, None}, TrackedSymbols -> {x, y, p}]
```

The only difference with the original code is that I've wrapped `p` with `Dynamic` in `Arrow`.

By the way, since `p == {x,y}`, you can actually replace `p` with `{x, y}` making the code a bit more elegant in this case:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{vector},
  vector = 
   Graphics[{Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[{x, y}]}], 
     Locator[Dynamic[{x, y}]]}];
  Deploy@Show[vector,
    PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, ImageSize -> 500]],
 {{x, 1, "Ax"}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{y, 1, "Ay"}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Heike's answer is correct, but I'd like to comment about *why* it's correct. Locators work very well, unless the expression that created the `Locator` gets re-generated as part of a `Dynamic` update. M-- makes some attempt to track re-generated locators, but it's a pathological problem which can't be solved in the most general case, and M-- is not as good as it could be in some specific cases. What Heike does here is to prevent the outer `Dynamic` implied by the `Manipulate` from firing by confining all references to `p` in more tightly scoped `Dynamic` constructs.

Comment: @Heike, This is great! Thanks Heike! And I know I tried linking the controllers by simply equating the variables in some way, but whatever way I tried it didn't work and I can't remember what I tried, but clearly not what you have shown me. I'm always learning!

Comment: @JohnFultz, Thank you for the explanation! I was going to ask the _why_ question so thank you for reading my mind. So that I am clear on this, with Heike's correction of `Dynamic[p]` in `Arrow` rather than just `p`, that `Dynamic` gets refreshed first before the implicit dynamic created by the Manipulate thereby allowing the `Arrow` to be recreated. Without the `Dynamic` within `Arrow` the `Locator` and `Arrow` do move a very tiny amount, but then stop. Is this due to how Manipulate sequences its evaluations, the first evaluation allowing the arrow to move, but then ... ok, I should just stop

Comment: One more thing, the `DynamicModule` that Heike added to the code isn't necessary to make this work (as I verified), just the `Dynamic[p]` within `Arrow`. Is the `DynamicModule` recommended though to localize the variable `vector` and/or are there other deeper reasons? As a physicist I am cursed by needing to know deeper reasons for things, but sometimes I just need to move on. Thank you all for putting up with my questions!

Comment: @JohnCarzoli I used the `DynamicModule` mainly to localize `vector`. It's usually a good idea to localize variables anyway but especially so in dynamic environments like `Manipulate`. If you don't, there is a big chance that different versions of the same `Manipulate` will interfere with each other.

Comment: @JohnCarzoli a correction to your logic. With the change to `Dynamic[p]`, there is never any need at all to refresh the implicit `Dynamic` created by the `Manipulate`. `Dynamic` only refreshes if a variable it directly evaluated changed.  The change makes it so that the only variable the implicit `Dynamic` depends upon is `vector`, and `vector` never changes (it contains internal `Dynamic`s that change, but that doesn't affect the value of `vector` itself).

Comment: @JohnFultz thank you for the clarification! This helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Heike fixes your problem. I want to add, that your use of `Manipulate` is rather unusual, because like you did it, it would be more appropriate to use `DynamicModule`. This is because the documentation an all tutorials suggest, that `Manipulate` is for not too complex situations. It can be used there, but the main area of `Manipulate` are situations where you display something and control it with `Sliders`,... which are give as separate argument to `Manipulate`.

As Heike showed, there is often a way to make it work too, but the mixture of *display* and *control* in your code, was what led to the error in the first place.
Let me explain this in more detail and start with a very simple example. This

```
Manipulate[Deploy[Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, p}], 
         Locator[Dynamic[p]]}, PlotRange -> 2]], 
   {{p, {1, 1}}, None}]
```

shows the same behavior you described and I believe it is, because `Manipulate` cannot handle the control inside the `Graphics` when it is combined with `Deploy` *and* the controlled variable appears in the graphics without `Dynamic`. Usually, no explicit `Dynamic` is needed inside `Manipulate` for such a simple situation. If you remove the `Deploy` it works. Try this the far more simpler version

```
Manipulate[Deploy[Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, p}]}, 
       PlotRange -> 2]], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

and you'll see, that it works without complaint, although we used `p` without `Dynamic`. Let's see whether we can adapt this to your piece of code. You will instantly object, that you need the special set-function inside your `Locator` to ensure, the sliders are moved with the locator. But look, you did the similar thing with `vector`: you just used `=` and it got dynamically updated:

```
Manipulate[
  vector = Graphics[{Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, p}]}]; 
  {x, y} = p;
  Deploy[Show[{vector}, PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, 
        ImageSize -> 500]], 
  Row[{"Ax", Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (x = #1; p[[1]] = x) & ], {-2, 2}], 
       Spacer[4], Dynamic[x]}], 
  Row[{"Ay", Manipulator[Dynamic[y, (y = #1; p[[2]] = y) & ], {-2, 2}], 
       Spacer[4], Dynamic[y]}], 
  {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}, 
  {{x, 1}, None}, 
  {{y, 1}, None}
]
```

This works as you would have expected it in the first place. Since you need an explicit `Manipulator` to make the x and y sliders work and since the `{x,y}=p` is not really nice, you should write a `DynamicModule` which is in my opinion the simpler version and clearer solution here:

```
DynamicModule[{p = {1, 1}, x = 1, y = 1},
 Panel[Column[{
    Row[{"Ax", Spacer[4], 
      Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (x = #1; p[[1]] = x) & ], {-2, 2}], 
      Spacer[4], Dynamic[x]}], 
    Row[{"Ay", Spacer[4], 
      Manipulator[Dynamic[y, (y = #1; p[[2]] = y) & ], {-2, 2}], 
      Spacer[4], Dynamic[y]}],
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[p, (p = #; x = p[[1]]; y = p[[2]]) &],
     Graphics[{Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[p]}]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, 
           ImageSize -> 500, Background -> White]
     ]
    }]
  ]
 ]
```

Note, that in all above examples I used the pieces of your code to make it more clear what I changed and what I put where. It is not necessary to use `p` *and* `x,y` and therefore a shorter version is

```
DynamicModule[{x = 1, y = 1}, 
  Panel[Column[{
    Row[{"Ax", Spacer[4], Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {-2, 2}], 
      Spacer[4], Dynamic[x]}], 
    Row[{"Ay", Spacer[4], Manipulator[Dynamic[y], {-2, 2}], 
      Spacer[4], Dynamic[y]}], 
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[{x, y}], 
      Graphics[{Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[{x,y}]}]}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1},{-2.1, 2.1}}, 
        ImageSize -> 500, Background -> White]
    ]}]
  ]
]
```

Comment: thank you for the additional information. I understand there are some limitations to Manipulate and I am always learning of new ones it seems. I'm trying to work within these limitations so as to create CDF files to include on my webpage for my students to interact with. Interactivity through a CDF file can only be done using Manipulate at least as far as I have read in the CDF documentation. However, your examples are great because I could also have versions of my demos in standard notebooks using the less restrictive DynamicModule and give these to students who have MMA. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnCarzoli, I never realized, that the CDF tutorial suggests, that only `Manipulates` can be used. I think this is just not true. I used `DynamicModule` in several CDFs and it alsways worked. You have to pay attention, that your dynamic content is really self-contained. To test this, you can copy the displayed manipulate into a new cdf, quit kernel or restart Mathematica and then it must still be usable. And, as Heike suggested, try to localize all variables you use. It's just clearer and less error prone.