# Manipulate Locator warping (snap to cursor)

Tags: graphics, dynamic, manipulate

I'm looking to have a Manipulator Locator that moves in discrete steps and requies the user to click on/near the locator position.. consider these two examples:

```
Manipulate[ 
        Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, q}], 
        PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {{x, 
            0}}, {{q, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, .2, Locator}]
```

The locator moves in discrete steps, but *warps* wherever you click.

Alternately this does nearly the same:

```
p = {0, 0};
Manipulate[ 
     Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, p}], Locator[Dynamic[p]]}, 
            PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {{x, 0}}]
```

Here you need to click *on* the locator to drag, but I have no way to specify the grid snap..

Any way to achieve both effects?

( this hack comes to mind as I'm posting ..

```
p = {0, 0};
    Manipulate[q = Round[5 p]/5; 
       Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, q}], Circle[q, .1], Locator[Dynamic[p]]}, 
          PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {{x, 0}}]
```

not very satisfactory though.. )

Edit:  Two working solutions based on Kuba's answer, plus a bit of tinkering:

```
p = {0, 0}; Manipulate[
       Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, p}], 
       Locator[Dynamic[
       p, (p = Round[ MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}], .2] ) &]]}, 
          PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {{x, 0}}]
```

..

```
  Manipulate[
      DynamicModule[{p = {0, 0}}, 
          Deploy@Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, p}], 
          Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = Round[ #, .2] ) &]]}, 
          PlotRange -> 1]], {{x, 0}}]
```

I remain a bit puzzled why this doesnt work:

```
        p = {0, 0}; Manipulate[
            Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, p}], 
            Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = Round[#, .2] ) &]]}, 
            PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {{x, 0}}]
```

(The incremental rounding causes the locator to drift away from the mouse pointer). I should rather say I see why this doesnt work, I dont see why DynamicModule fixes it.

Comment: Seems like a job for `LocatorPane` (possibly with `DynamicModule`).

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29441/5478

Comment: Thanks for the link..but LocatorPane seem to have the same issue of warping unless I'm missing something.

Comment: ["warp"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warp) = "bend or twist" is not a good description of the behavior of the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
DynamicModule[{p = {0, 0}},
               Deploy@Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, p}], 
                                Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = Round /@ #) &]]}
                               , PlotRange -> 5, Frame -> True]
             ]
```

I'm not sure what do you mean by warp, dragging is warping too?

Comment: Warp == In my first example you can click anyplace and the locator jumps to wherever you click.  This answer is just about what I need -- for some reason if I do the rounding in Locator[Dynamic[]] inside Manipulate[] the locator doesnt track properly with the mouse cursor.  Nesting DynamicModule[] inside Manipulate[] seems to work though.

Comment: I'm glad it works like you need. You can skip `Manipulate` and work with `DynamicModule`/`Dynamic`, I find `Manipulate` useful only for simple GUIs, in other cases it could be frustrating to achieve the result we are after.

Comment: In the end I think "dont use manipulate" is the real best answer..related link http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/a-problem-with-deploy-and-locator-in-a-manipulate. (halirutan's answer)